# How do I force all Graphics Text to be StandardForm?

Tags: notebooks, fonts

I've been playing around for while trying to determine how to get all graphic objects to use StandardForm fonts. That is, I want all axes labelling, titling, legends, inserted text, etc., for 2D/3D graphics to use StandardForm. Forever and always unless explicitly overridden.

I'm getting somewhat overwhelmed with all of the options in the Option Inspector and if anyone has a suggestion I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done by setting

```
SetOptions[Graphics, FormatType -> StandardForm]
```

If you also want to get this format in text labels for `Plot`, you'd have to set the options for that command analogously. This isn't so obvious because the output of `Plot` is also of head `Graphics`. The `FormatType` specification for `Graphics` doesn't get applied to `Plot` results, however.